# I need to find specific strings within a whole server project which I don't have the whole source. What can I do?

Tags: java, sql, jsp

So I'm battling an endless chaotic system.

There's a glassfish server which provides several reports from a sql server. I need to find which pages are accessing what tables.

The system is not homogenous, meaning that some pages might have their SQL query directly in the jsp page while others might have a separate DAO.Java file.

I do have the Java sources inside each directory.

My only idea would be to do individual searches for each table I'm looking for, but this will take loads of time... and in the future I'll have to do this again.

Maybe there's a better way? Maybe I could index all lines of code in the server? Any suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if some pages use JPA too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this is an old question. Maybe it should be closed. But if anyone finds themselves in a similar situation:

- Group all source code you have. Got code without source? Decompile it.
- Get a *nix system.
- Use cat and grep to quickly run through everything.